# Distribution of Minimal Canonical Heights of Non-Torsion Points on Mordell Curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $\hat{h}_d(\cdot)$ be the Neron-Tate canonicial height function for the curve $E_d:y^2 = x^3+d$ ($d$ is 6th power free). I also assume that $E_d$ has rank one so that, by the quadratic behavior of $\hat{h}$, that for a generator $Q_d$ of $E_d(\mathbb{Q})$ the minimal non-zero value of $|\hat{h}_d(\cdot)|$ is $|\hat{h}_d(Q_d)|$. (**Note:** I also would like a way to verify that this statement is true, as the quadratic behavior is only up to $O(1)$.)

What I have so far regarding the question is rudimentary data gathered from computations on Sage, from which I found that this minimal value seems to increase on average as the generator grows in Weil height. This is according to my expectation, although the growth seems quite erratic.

My question is if there is any idea of how the value $|\hat{h}_d(Q_d)|$ evolves as $d$ ranges over the 6th-power free integers, where values are "plotted" against $d$ of increasing magnitude: 0, $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$, and so on. I understand this is a question whose answer is not really concretely known, but I would like to get any results I can about it, such as asymptotic behavior or average value. As I am also researching this distribution, any links or titles to works the community knows that address this topic or anything similar would be much appreciated!

Comment: The analogue in the number theory case would be to look at the heights of the fundamental units of $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ as $d$ varies over positive squarefree integers. Here you see the growth is also erratic; the (logarithmic) height can be as small as $\log d$ and as large as $d^{1/2}$ or so. Getting "average" results is difficult because it is hard to uncouple the regulator from the class number, but conjecturally the upper estimate $O(d^{1/2 \pm \epsilon})$ is presumably the correct one. Presumably you have something similar here; you might be able to compute averages of...

Comment: The L-values, but it might be difficult to uncouple the height of a generator from Sha, since the L-value only gives the height of the Heegner point. I would first look for references on the L-values which are probably easier to understand (both specifically and in the average sense). Another direction is to look at results of people like Matthew Baker on height bounds for points on elliptic curves over abelian extensions (particularly if E has CM).

Comment: @user760870 One question: What do you mean by uncoupling the quantities? Is it as in Equations 1.5 and 1.6 of: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.7738.pdf ?

Comment: The paper you linked to *in the comments* is 100% on the topic of your question and it's hard to imagine why you would possibly post this question if you were already aware of this paper (or why you wouldn't mention it). Anyway, the first step is obviously to read this paper.  I will not make any further comments on this question.